# Question about definition of compact of a matrix Lie group

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

In "Lie Groups, Lie Algebras and Representations" by Brian C. Hall, a matrix Lie group is defined in sec. 1.1 in the following way: A matrix Lie group $G$ is a subgroup $G \leq \mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ with the following property: If $(A_m)_m^\infty$ is a sequence in $G$ that converges to some matrix $A$, then either $A \in G$ or $A$ is not invertible (i.e. $A \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ but $A \notin \mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$). This is equivalent to saying that $G$ should be a closed subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$. See also the discussion in this [Math SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2617705/definition-of-matrix-lie-group).

Later, in the same book in sec. 1.3, a compact matrix Lie group is defined as a matrix Lie group $G \leq \mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ which is compact in the relative topology of $M_n(\mathbb{C})\cong \mathbb{R}^{2n^2}$. It is further stated (by the Heine-Borel theorem) that $G$ is compact if and only if i) For any sequence $(A_m)_m^\infty \in G$ that converges to some $A$, then $A \in G$ (i.e. closure) and ii) There exists $C \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall A \in G$ and $\forall j,k \in \{1,...,n\}$ we have $|A_{jk}| \leq C$ (i.e. boundedness).

My question is simply if condition i) above is not redundant, since this closure property is already part of the definition of $G$ as a matrix Lie group. It can be noted that in condition i), it is *not* stated that $A$ is necessarily in $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$, i.e. $A$ could be any matrix in $A \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$. Is this the important distinction? If so, what would be an example of a matrix Lie group $G$ that is *not* closed in the sense of ii)?

Comment: You are right, it is redundant.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks for your comment! What about my example in the last paragraph, though?

Comment: Your example is not a group. You can replace it by $\operatorname{GL}(n,\Bbb C)$ itself.

Comment: If a sequence of nonsingular matrices converges to a singular one, then the inverse sequence is unbounded.

Comment: @AnneBauval Ok fair enough, it obviously does not contain the identity matrix (my bad), so I'll delete my non-example.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Yes, I removed my example since it was actually not a group (is this what you were getting at)? However, how can we see that they are equivalent? Are you saying that there are no matrix Lie groups which fail to be closed in the sense of ii)?

Comment: Did you read my last comment? I was only discussing compact subgroups.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Sorry, I think I see what you mean now. Are you saying that i) is redundant since we also require ii). That is, if we have a matrix Lie group that is closed as a subgroup of GL(n,C) but not in the sense of ii), then there is a sequence of matrices in G that converge to a singular matrix. However, in that case, G is not bounded, so it is not compact anyway. Is this a correct understanding?

Comment: Right!.........

Comment: @MoisheKohan Ok, thanks! By the way, (disregarding the question of compactness) do you know of a good example of a matrix Lie group that is *not* closed in the sense of ii) ?

Comment: Of course. Think of the case $n=1$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Well, ok one can construct trivial examples like $G = \mathbb{R}_+ \leq \mathrm{GL}(1,\mathbb{C})$ and consider the sequence $A_k = 1/k$.